# Invalid argument Unable to print text using drawtext using ffmpeg

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am trying to add text and time stamp on video but not able to print the simple text on it.

```
String[] complexCommand = {"-f", "3gp", "-i", videoPath, "-s", height + "x" + width, "-r",
 "17", "drawtext=fontfile='file://android_asset/font_eight.ttf':fontsize=20:text='test':x=10:y=100",
  "-vcodec", "libx264", "-vb", "2000k", "-preset", "fast", "-f", "3gp", dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/out.3gp"};
 
 ffmpeg -f 3gp -i /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20171211_105946.3gp -s 1920x1080
 -r 17 drawtext='fontfile=file://android_asset/font_eight.ttf:fontsize=20:text=test:x=10:y=100 
-vcodec libx264 -vb 2000k -preset fast -f 3gp /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Video/out.3gp
```

***-- Edited Question ---***

**Error:**

Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file

[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0xf5ba0730] impossible to init fontconfig

[AVFilterGraph @ 0xf5b89040] Error initializing filter 'drawtext' with args 'fontfile=file://android_asset/font_eight.ttf:fontsize=32:text=test:fontcolor=white:x=0:y=0'

**Error opening filters!**

Same command runs on windows with no error, But when I converted it for mobile device and tested getting error of font-path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

drawtext is a video filter, so it has to be passed as an argument to `-vf` or `-filter_complex` (used when filtering multiple streams).

So,

per Gyan, Dec 13
`-vf drawtext=fontsize=20:text='aaa':x=10:y=100`

Comment: Please proofread your commands: `fontsize=20:=text` --> remove `:=`

Comment: hi, @Mulvya  I am not able to use the the command on android device, can u help me out